# Enabling Memory Dump Performance Impact

Tags: windows-server

Our Windows Servers are crashing and we can't understand why. Microsoft support advised us to enable Memory Dump for troubleshooting. What are performance implications for enabling Memory Dump? What are performance implications for enabling Complete Memory Dump, which requires increasing Paging File to exceed amount of RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your servers are crashing then there will be no performance impact but the loss of service. The paging file must the size of your physical RAM plus 257MB.